# Adding object properties dynamically "directly" to `this` in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible in JavaScript/TypeScript to add properties from an object "directly" to `this` of a class (without looping through the object properties and create them this way)?

Something like this does not work (as far as I can tell):

```
const TEST:any = {
    case1: {
        ing: "ing1",
        ping: "ping1"       
    },
    case2: {
        ing: "ing2",
        ping: "ping2"       
    }
}

class Test {

    constructor() {
        if (true) {
            Object.assign(this, TEST.case1);                        
        } else {
            Object.assign(this, TEST.case2);            
        }
    }
}
```

So I could use it like this:

```
let test = new Test();
console.log(test.ing); // outputs "ing1"
```

Comment: Seems to work in http://babeljs.io/repl/ if you drop the `:any` TS type from `TEST` declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(true)` makes it always go into the `if`, never into the else.  Your code works as expected. Note that you cannot declare a variable to be a specific type, it looks like you are trying to mix ES6 and TypeScript.

Maybe you meant the following (http://www.es6fiddle.net/ikqxpqh4/):

```
const TEST/* : any (Type information is TypeScript not ES6) */ = {
    case1: {
        ing: "ing1",
        ping: "ping1"       
    },
    case2: {
        ing: "ing2",
        ping: "ping2"       
    }
}

class Test {

    constructor(test) {
        if (test) {
            Object.assign(this, TEST.case1);                        
        } else {
            Object.assign(this, TEST.case2);            
        }
    }
}
var t1 = new Test(false);
var t2 = new Test(true);
console.log(JSON.stringify(t1), JSON.stringify(t2));
// {"ing":"ing2","ping":"ping2"} {"ing":"ing1","ping":"ping1"}
```